# How do I modify this SQL schema to constrain data in tables?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Newbie in need of help.

I'm creating a small database.

[image]

I want to constrain data in a couple of tables - Lender and Pingtree. The ProviderType table contains lookup data and contains either 'Lender' or 'Pingtree'. How can I modify this structure so that the Lender table only can contain Lender types and Pingtree, Pingtree types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that `ProviderTypeID` is the column in the `Provider` table that distinguishes between the two types, then you must add this same column to both the `Lender` and `Pingtree` tables, add a suitable key (if it doesn't already exist) in `Provider` on `ID, ProviderTypeId`, and then add a composite `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to the `Lender` and `Pingtree` tables that include these columns.

While this may sound like a drag, it is a known pattern called supertyping/subtyping. When the supertype (Provider) can be multiple subtypes, you don't need the `TypeId` column. But when the subtypes are mutually exclusive, this is what you must do.

It might look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Lender ADD ProviderTypeId tinyint NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_Lender_ProviderTypeID DEFAULT (1)
   CONSTRAINT CK_Lender_ProviderTypeID_Is_Lender CHECK (ProviderTypeID = 1);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Pingtree ADD ProviderTypeId tinyint NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_Pingtree_ProviderTypeID DEFAULT (2)
   CONSTRAINT CK_Pingtree_ProviderTypeID_Is_Pingtree CHECK (ProviderTypeID = 2);

-- Any of a PK, UNIQUE constraint, or unique index will do
ALTER TABLE dbo.Provider ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Provider_ID_ProviderTypeID
   UNIQUE (ID, ProviderTypeID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Lender DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Lender_ProviderId;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Lender ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Lender_ProviderId_ProviderTypeId
   FOREIGN KEY (ID, ProviderTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.Provider (ID, ProviderTypeID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.PingTree DROP CONSTRAINT FK_PingTree_ProviderId;
ALTER TABLE dbo.PingTree ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PingTree_ProviderId_ProviderTypeId
   FOREIGN KEY (ID, ProviderTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.Provider (ID, ProviderTypeID);
```

If written correctly (specifying the column list on `INSERT`) your stored procedures and application SQL code should not have to change.